# Google Maps doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637755/google-map-api-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin) and have a great result on desktops but in mobile browsers maps are simply blank (checked on Android, iOS). Seems that the script is not running on mobile (javascript is allowed in browsers) as the resulting page have no executed code in div#map_leads.

[This](http://cp310939.cpanel.tech-logol.ru/tsolutions/contact/) is the case.

Can anybody help to solve it?

Made one more clear [page](http://cp310939.cpanel.tech-logol.ru/tsolutions/111.php) which contains only the map and everything works fine... will try to find the wrong code on the website.

I've found out that the reason for the map is not working is the following javascript:

```
(function() {

function t(e) {
this.path=e;
var t=this.path.split("."),n=t.slice(0,t.length-1).join("."),r=t[t.length-1];
this.at_2x_path=n+"@2x."+r
}

function n(e) {
this.el=e,this.path=new t(this.el.getAttribute("src"));
var n=this;
this.path.check_2x_variant(function(e){e&&n.swap()})
}

var e=typeof exports=="undefined"?window:exports;

e.RetinaImagePath=t,
t.confirmed_paths=[],
t.prototype.is_external=function(){
return!!this.path.match(/^https?\:/i)&&!this.path.match("//"+document.domain)
},
t.prototype.check_2x_variant=function(e){
var n,
r=this;

if(this.is_external())return e(!1);

if(this.at_2x_path in t.confirmed_paths)return e(!0);

n=new XMLHttpRequest,
n.open("HEAD",this.at_2x_path),
n.onreadystatechange=function(){
return n.readyState!=4?e(!1):n.status>=200&&n.status<=399?(t.confirmed_paths.push(r.at_2x_path),
e(!0)):e(!1)},
n.send()
},

e.RetinaImage=n,
n.prototype.swap=function(e){
function n(){
t.el.complete?(
t.el.setAttribute("width",t.el.offsetWidth),
t.el.setAttribute("height",t.el.offsetHeight),
t.el.setAttribute("src",e)
):setTimeout(n,5)}
typeof e=="undefined"&&(e=this.path.at_2x_path);
var t=this;
n()},

e.devicePixelRatio>1&&(window.onload=function(){
var e=document.getElementsByTagName("img"),t=[],r,i;
for(r=0;r<e.length;r++)i=e[r],t.push(new n(i))})})();
```

I've broke it into lines by myself as in origin it is written in line. Will try to fix it - think that there's something wrong with img element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added map function to the end of the posted script and it works fine. Sorry for wasting your time!