# Embed styled Google Map in a Wordpress Genesis Child Theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, google-maps

I created a custom-styled Google Map overlay in Snazzy Maps and tried going through Google's Developer courses to understand where to place the code, but it looks like everything Google is referring to is an HTML sheet, and all I have access to is CSS and PHP files for my theme (Cafe Pro from StudioPress.com, based on the Genesis parent theme).

My child theme didn't come loaded with a header.php file, so I tried copying it from the parent files and into Cafe Pro, as I read on one site that you needed the header.php to embed a stylized map into a Wordpress theme.

All I want to do is to create a map that looks and acts like this (full page, interactive, styled in black & white):

http://cobblehilldigital.com/contact/

and put it, full-width (100%), into the bottom "Contact" section of my page: http://kgshowroom.com/wordpress/ (near the bottom of the front page, with the black background). There is a map there now, but it is not configured with any custom style and it is only a portion of the page in width.

I tried following the directions from the "Styled Maps" and the "Adding a Google Map to your website" Google docs (I can't post more than 2 links here, so I can't include it) but am unable to access the HTML in my theme other than adding snippets to the  and .

I am on a self-hosted Wordpress site (version 4.1), so I should have full access to customization.

Is there any help for those working with php or CSS files with embedding styled Google Maps?

And I apologize if I'm asking in the wrong place; it's 2:15 am and I've been trying to figure this out for 6 hours.

Comment: You can try something like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637755/google-map-api-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin) to add a map using wordpress

Comment: Thank you, @larryp. I'll see if that works and report back if I can't quite get it to work.