# How to insert Google maps into Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to insert google maps into my wordpress site.
Because I want circles on my map I can't use plugins which insert the map for me.
So I want to use the code from this site [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple?hl=de) which should work I think.
I copied the code and inserted it on my page into an editor which *can show* js and html.
I also get a browser key, replaced the code at the specified place and confirmed my domain.

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
```

But nothing show up at the page. No error, no maps, no empty space.

Now I thought that the reason could be that I don't add any version.
(If no version is added usually automatically the experimental version is used)
But nevertheless I tried it with v=3 which should be the release version.

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3key=MY_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
```

And now I get the errors *NoApiKeys*, *InvalidVersion* and *MissingKeyMapError*.
But why ? The version should be valid and my key as well.
I made *many different* tutorials and stuff like that but nothing works.

Did anyone knows what to change to get this work?

Here is the whole code, but it is the same like that on the google page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {
  chicago: {
    center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
    population: 2714856
  },
  newyork: {
    center: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005},
    population: 8405837
  },
  losangeles: {
    center: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243},
    population: 3857799
  },
  vancouver: {
    center: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1},
    population: 603502
  }
};

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    });
  }
}

</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3key=MY_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I would be happy if everyone who "dislikes" this will write a short comment why.
I tried to ask good questions and if something is missing or wrong I will change it.

Comment: Are you inserting the whole code (from doctype till the end of the html) into the default WordPress content editor?

Comment: yes everything. is that wrong ?

Comment: Well yes :) You are trying to insert a page into a page and that is not allowed (except using iframes...).  You should add the script for the map in a map.js file or add it as a part of you main js file. The styles should go in the style.css file. Call google maps api from your function.php file using [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). Then you should just add the div for the map `<div id="map"></div>`, where you want it to show up (note: You can add it only once per page using the same `id`).

Comment: Ahh ok, but if I use a foreign theme I have to write a child theme , right ? Can I insert the whole code in a iframe too, or is there any easier way to do this ? Just to test it if that is the reason of all the errors?

Answer (score 0):

i would debug probably by first listing only simple map thus skipping all this code below

```
  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
```

it will help me to pinpoint which code is creating issue and then will take on from there.

Comment: also tried that with the same results like before... but thank you.

Comment: ok, it means you need to use wordpress way as this is not using iframe way. check this for pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637755/google-map-api-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin